# The number of onto functions possible from set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to set $B=\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $f(1)=a$ and $f(2)$ is not $b$?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of onto functions possible from set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to set $B=\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that $f(1)=a$ and $f(2)$ is not $b$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of onto functions with image containing $1$ element is $1$

- Computation of the number of onto functions with image containing  $2$ elements;

If the image contains two elements; the image is one of $\{a,b\} , \{a,c\}$ or $\{a,d\}$

with $\{a,b\}$ there are $2^4 - 1 = 15$ ways, with $\{a,c\}$ or $\{a,d\}$ there are $2^5-1 = 31$ ways so total is 77 ways

- Computation of the number of onto functions with image containing 3 elements;

If the image is $\{a,b,c\}$ or $\{a,b,d\}$ there are $2*3^4 - 15 -31-1 = 115$ ways

If the image is $\{a,c,d\}$ there are $3^5-31-31-1 = 180$ ways

so total is $410$ ways

- Computation of all functions such that $f(1) = a$ and $f(2) \neq b$

The number of ways is $3(4^4) = 768$

Hence the number of onto functions is $768-410-77-1 = 280$

Comment: Your solution is very good, very very thank you for that...but my request is can you please provide me some good  references...about this method so that I can study it further and I'll try to use this method with couple of more problems I have ...

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle   . Inclusion exclusion principle should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since f(1) must be equal to a we have no choice there.  f(2) must NOT be b so it can be any of a, c, or d so there are 3 choices for f(2). f(3), f(4), f(5), and f(6) each can be any of a, b, c, d so there are 4 choices for each of those.  That gives a total of 3(4)(4)(4)(4)= 768 different functions.

Comment: This does not count all the onto functions; for instance you have also counted the string (a,a,a,a,a,a)